# Css not loaded on ssl page with wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ssl

I have a wordpress site : http://www.istebuemlak.com

In this page : https://www.istebuemlak.com/ilan-ver , css is not loading properly.

This is the only page with ssl connection. However when I check from firebug, I realize there are no css files sent. What could be the reason for this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Flush your browser Cache or try other browsers
2. Check your browser plug-ins if they are causing the problem
3. Check if your page has a css link in the code